# C# Console App - Auto-Truncate 140 Chars Tweets

Tags: c#, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have a C# console app and would like to post tweets.  I'm currently using TweetSharp as an api wrapper.  When posting tweets over 140 chars, I get a forbidden error.  Is there a way to auto-truncate these tweets to 140 chars?

I tried manually doing so via .Substring(0, 140), but I think TweetSharp auto-converts to UTF-8 when posting, and if I have an ampersand in the string, TweetSharp will convert my 140 truncated text string to a 141+ string which then fails to post.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

Just truncate your string and remove the forbidden remains with the attached code.

```
var myResult = TruncateString(yourinput, 137).VariableSafeString();
```

Here is truncating by using remove.

```
private string TruncateString(string input, int length)
{
    if (input == null || input.Length < length)
        return input;

    return input.Remove(length, input.Length - length) + "...";
}
```

And some extension methods

```
public static class StringMethods
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Remove nordic characters and accents
    /// Example
    ///     "ÅÄÖ / \\íå íàøëîñü ôîðìû äëÿ îòïðàâêè" will be returned as "AAO / \\ia iaøeinu oiðiu aey ioiðaaee"
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string RemoveDiacritics(this string s)
    {
        string normalizedString = s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < normalizedString.Length; i++)
        {
            char c = normalizedString[i];
            if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
                stringBuilder.Append(c);
        }
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Make string variable safe
    /// Example
    ///     "ÅÄÖ / \\íå íàøëîñü ôîðìû äëÿ îòïðàâêè" will be returned as "AAOiaiaeinuoiiuaeyioiaaee"
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string VariableSafeString(this string s)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(s.RemoveDiacritics(), "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "");
    } 
}
```

I suppose you might have to adjust the regexp a bit. Good luck and have fun :)